# Issue with pointers to templated virtual base class

Tags: c++, class, templates, virtual

The regular way of defining an interface uses virtual base classes like:

```
class BaseClass_B
{
public:
    BaseClass_B() {}
    virtual ~BaseClass_B() {}
    virtual void method(const int &fParam) const = 0;
};

template <class tDerivedClassParam>
class DerivedClass_B : public BaseClass_B
{
    void method(const int &fParam) const override final
    {
        // Do something useful
    }

};

class FinalClass_B
{
public:
    using TypeAlias = int;
};
```

Then I can create a derived object and assign its address to both a derived object pointer and a base pointer:

```
DerivedClass_B<FinalClass_B> object_B;
DerivedClass_B<FinalClass_B> *ptr_B;
BaseClass_B *basePtr_B;

ptr_B = &object_B;
basePtr_B = &object_B;
```

However, when I try to do the same, having a templated virtual base class:

```
template <class tBaseClassParam>
class BaseClass_A
{
public:
    BaseClass_A() {}
    virtual ~BaseClass_A() {}
    virtual void method(const int &fParam) const = 0;
};

//
// Note that BaseClass_A<> is defined using a type alias from FinalClass_A
//
template <class tDerivedClassParam>
class DerivedClass_A : public BaseClass_A<typename tDerivedClassParam::TypeAlias>
{
    void method(const int &fParam) const override final
    {
        // Doe something useful
    }
};

class FinalClass_A
{
public:
    using TypeAlias = int;
};
```

I get an error at the last row when trying:

```
DerivedClass_A<FinalClass_A> object_A;
DerivedClass_A<FinalClass_A> *ptr_A;
BaseClass_A<FinalClass_A> *basePtr_A;

ptr_A = &object_A;
basePtr_A = &object_A;  //<-- Generates error
```

The compiler error I get is:

```
error: cannot convert ‘DerivedClass_A<FinalClass_A>*’ to ‘BaseClass_A<FinalClass_A>*’ in assignment
```

What am I missing???

BTW, I'm on C++14.

Comment: "virtual base class" means something different than how you're using it. You could say this is an "interface base class".

Comment: In general templates (static polymorphism) and virtual functions do not mix well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What am I missing???

`basePtr_A` is not a pointer to a `DerivedClass_A<FinalClass_A>` or a base class thereof.

`BaseClass_A<FinalClass_A::TypeAlias>* basePtr_A;` would be a base class pointer you could use in the assignment `basePtr_A = &object_A;`.

---

Another option to make that assignment work is to change the definition of `DerivedClass_A`:

```cpp
template <class tDerivedClassParam>
class DerivedClass_A : public BaseClass_A<tDerivedClassParam> {
    void method(const int &fParam) const override final {
    }
};
```